# Missing required parameter

Tags: php, html, laravel

> Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.status-order.update] [URI: admin/status-order/{status_order}] [Missing parameter: status_order].

I don't understand where the error is, here is my controller:

```
 public function show(Order $order)
{
    $data = DB::table('order_menu')
        ->join('menus', 'menus.id', '=', 'order_menu.menu_id')
        ->join('orders', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_menu.order_id')
        ->select('orders.*', 'menus.name', 'order_menu.quantity')
        ->where('orders.id', $order->id)
        ->get();

    return view('admin.status-order.edit')->with([
        'order' => $order,
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, Order $order)
{
    $order->status = $request->status;
    $order->save();
    return redirect()->route('admin.status-order.index');
}
```

And for the edit.blade.php :

```
 <form action="{{ route('admin.status-order.update', $order) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        <h6 style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px">Order #{{ $order->order_number }}</h6>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

For the route:

```
 Route::namespace("App\Http\Controllers\Admin")->prefix("admin")->name("admin.")->middleware('can:adminpage')->group(function () {
   Route::resource("/status-order", OrderStatusController::class);
 });
```

Comment: Share your route file. You are sending an object of `Order` in `action` of form. I guess your route need and string or integer.

Comment: @Jayant I've add the routes to my question

Comment: Have you try to add `{{ route('admin.status-order.update', ['status_order' => $order->status_order`) }}` and in method `update($status_order)`. Can you please mention or update your `'admin.status-order.update'` route. You are using a resource controller and update use PUT/PATCH method and need one parameter. Please see the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @Jayant I've tried as you suggested but still got the same error

Comment: @aufa Please run command ```php artisan route:list``` and paste ```/status-order``` resource routes

Comment: The error tells you the `status_order` param is missing. [Checking the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes), you can see the code you have to generate the URL for a named route with a parameter is not correct. Jayant is right, though maybe the variable name is wrong: `{{ route('admin.status-order.update', ['status_order' => $order->id]) }}` (edited - you probably need `$order->id`).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code. You have resource route and update method required `$id` parameter. I have pass one `id` params to your view and used in `form` action. See the below code
`show` function have params but i have new param called `id`.

```
 public function show(Order $order)
{
   .
   .
   . 
    return view('admin.status-order.edit')->with([
        'order' => $order,
        'data' => $data,
        'id' => $order->id  
    ]);
}
```

Used `id` in the `form` action and set `order->status` value in input tag. see below code

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.status-order.update', $id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        ......
        ......
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" id="name" required value="{{ $order->status }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Now when you submit your form, `update` method will get an `$id` params as per resource route and will update your table.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {   
        Order::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => $request->status]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.status-order.index');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {dd($th->__toString());
        throw $th;
    }
}
```

But in your case `status_order` is not found. So you have to set a new route and pass one params `status_order`. see below

`Route::put('/status-order-update/{status_order}', OrderStatusController@update)->name('status.order.update');`.

Update method will be like `public function update(Request $request, $statusOrder)`

`Form` in blade be like `action={{ route('status.order.update', ['status_order' => $order->status])}}`.

Please comment if it helps.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it